# Problems with try() inside foreach() in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, try-catch

I am trying to use the `try()` function to deal with errors that are occurring in my parallelised for loop:

```
results <- foreach (i = 1:2, .errorhandling = 'remove') %dopar% {
    res <- try(myfun(i), TRUE)
}
```

with

```
myfun <- function(i){
    if (i==1) return(rnorm(1))
    else stop('error')
}
```

I get the following error message

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: Error in myfun(i) : error
```

How can I get the foreach "loop" to ignore the error message (or at least deal with it a little more elegantly)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` and deal with the error appropriately.  Here the error is ignored (returning NULL)

```
results <- foreach (i = 1:2) %dopar% {
    res <- tryCatch({
        myfun(i)
    }, error=function(e) NULL)
}
```

or just using the builtin `.errorhandling='remove'` as you have, without the `try` should remove the errors already.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use the "remove" or "pass" error handling in `foreach`, you don't need to catch the error yourself. Here are the results when setting the error handling to "remove":

```
> foreach (i = 1:2, .errorhandling = 'remove') %dopar% {
+     myfun(i)
+ }
[[1]]
[1] 1.314854
```

Here are the results when using "pass":

```
> foreach (i = 1:2, .errorhandling = 'pass') %dopar% {
+     myfun(i)
+ }
[[1]]
[1] 0.7247509

[[2]]
<simpleError in myfun(i): error>
```

By using `try`, the error is caught and then translated to a "try-error" object by the `try` function, hiding the error from `foreach` until the the `clusterApplyLB` function (which is used to implement the `doParallel` backend) notices the "try-error" object in the list of results and throws an error in the master process. I would call that a bug in `doParallel`.

Note that the solution given by @LegalizeIt works because it returns a `NULL` rather than a "try-error" object, thus avoiding the bug in `doParallel`.